tex pdf conversion to word
Here are (I guess known) issues when trying to convert a .tex generated pdf (overleaf) to word format (.doc, docx).
for e.g.
citations are no longer linkable (cross reference)
formula, equations are completely out of order
 appears in the place of apostrophe in author's and 'fi' in the word figure, specific etc.
This is the case with adobe conversion as well as some other applications.
Haven't tried pandoc as not very familiar with tex commands.
Would like to try this answer but unsure how to or where to put this code in tex.
Is there a simple way to use pandoc/or similar and then ensure word document has cros referencing citations?
Can .tex file from overleaf be used as a source in a Tex distribution software (other than overleaf) which use pandoc to generate a proper word format file?

If you have the tex code of the document, just do the pandoc run shown in the answer to the linked question in a terminal window. The command is not TeX code but a usual command line to be used in a shell, cmd.exe, PowerShell or similar! Note, that you also should install a TeX distribution before using pandoc. If you want to convert a PDF to Word, this would be off-topic.

BTW: Because you are using tag [tag:overleaf]: AFAIK you cannot use pandoc on overleaf. And IMHO question about how to use pandoc on overleaf would be off-topic.

Or if you are interested in how to make better convertible PDFs using LaTeX → [tag:tagged-pdf].  And please also try to make your question clear.

Welcome to TeX.SE!

@cabohah so there's a .tex file from overleaf. so can this .tex file be used as a source in a Tex distribution application with pandoc as a packge? what Tex distribution do you recommend?

@bonCodigo pandoc isn't a package in a TeX distribution. you install pandoc separately. there are two main TeX distributions: TeX Live and MikTeX. if you are on anything but windows, I'd recommend TeX Live. if you are on windows, pick whichever you prefer. overleaf is just an editor. it uses TeX Live.

Is always a bad business write in LateX to export to Word. Soon or later you will make something in LateX that is not exportable. If you really need both formats, make the source with the simpler but easily exportable markdown.

@cfr  I see. I guess in that case just rely on pdf editing? it's not as user friendly as word app for sure, but doesn't seem like there's another way out. It's surprising how overleaf or other software doesn't provide a properly formatted .tex to word like output.

what are you actually trying to do? editing pdfs produced by tex sounds like the wrong solution.
